# Unexpected text wrapping on divs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm experiencing a weird issue with a library I'm developing and it boils down to this code:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 200px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -50px; top: 50px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -100px; top: 100px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -150px; top: 150px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -200px; top: 200px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code here is very simple: we have the same text in differently placed `div`s. The position is all the `div`s differ by. I would expect that all five texts are displayed identically, whether that is in one line or broken into multiple lines. However, the divs to the left don't have text wrapping, the ones towards the right do.

This behaviour is consistent in Chrome 83 and Firefox 77 and Edge 83.

The culprit seems to be the negative left, because if I remove those, it displays consistently (I can't do that in the actual application though given how those offsets are calculated).

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 0px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 50px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 150px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 200px">
            Hello some text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug in all those browsers? Or is this somehow logical?

Actual rendering:
[image: actual]

Expected rendering:
[image: expected]

Comment: try setting `right: 0;` to main outer `div`

Comment: the reason why this is happening is, you have set the outer most `div` to `absolute`.  by setting `right: 0`, it will occupy the space of the to the right end of the parent. in your case the parent is `body`.

Comment: Looks like the explanation given by the @Fareed Khan can answer your question. If you think that this can be the answer to your question then you can accept that suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

#### Code not working for you because of the reason

The code that is not working in your case is because only the first child `div` is itself inside the parent `div` because the `left` property is `zero` for it, while the rest of the `div's` are going outside of the parent `div` because you are giving them `negative` `left` property.

[image]

If I try to insert another i-e second number `div` by giving it `left` property of `50px` it will behave normally because it will be treated as a member of its parent `div`.

[image]

#### Code working for you because of the reason

That's the reason your working code is having parent `div` `left` property of `0px` and so that first child `left property` of `200px` then for second use `150px` and so on as a result of it all of the children are treated as a member of their `parent div`. `negative number` is not an option here.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 200px; background-color:red; top: 0px">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 50px;  background-color:red;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px;  background-color:green; top: 100px">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px;  background-color:green; top: 150px">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px;  background-color:green; top: 200px">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
</div>
```

But still if you want a solution without messing around with `left` property, `width:100%`is what you need then:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 200px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:100%;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -50px; top: 50px; width:100%;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -100px; top: 100px; width:100%;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -150px; top: 150px; width:100%;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -200px; top: 200px; width:100%;">
    Hello some text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to set width of all divs to get expected behavior. You just need to set width of the container div to 100%, or change its positioning to `relative`, which do the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

For your div set up width and they will stay as expecting.

Comment: See comment on [the other answer that suggest setting a width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62485034/985296)